# Using DSE Search from CQL on Thrift Error

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm getting the following warning and it's flooding my cassandra logs:

```
WARN [ReadStage:26] 2014-12-04 08:35:33,158 ThriftSolrSecondaryIndexSearcher.java (line 28) Running Solr queries on Thrift tables is discouraged and not supported for production environments!
```

I know we have solr_query in some of our code, does this mean we need to upgrade our tables to cql?

**Using**: DSE 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you should only get this warning if you are accessing cassandra using thrift rpc or cql2, i.e. hector,  cassandra-cli, etc **and** using the DSE Search syntax (`solr_query`). If you use one of the DataStax drivers you will not receive the error (even if the tables are COMPACT STORAGE).